# Replace all characters not included in characters OR sequences list

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i am working on C# code that should replace all unknown (unknown = other that available) characters to one character choosen by me (e.g. '?'). Available characters can be single characters, **OR a sequence of two or more characters**.

For example:

```
Input string: AXBY@@CZ
Available characters or sequences: A, B, C, @@
Desired output: A?B?@@C?
```

Other example:

```
Input string: AXBY@CZ
Available characters or sequences: A, B, C, @@
Desired output: A?B??C?
```

I want to achieve this using a regex expression. The closest i got to the solution is a regex like this:

```
(?!@@|[ABC]).
```

But in an example of input string like this it will result in a wrong result:

```
Input string: AXBY@@CZ
Result from above regex: A?B?@?C?
Instead of wanted by me: A?B?@@C?
```

How i can achieve my goal?

Comment: Match them and join the match values.

Comment: Can you post a regex for my example case?

Comment: The problem is that you consume only one character with your negative look ahead assertion. The first @ matches but the second will be removed. You can do that using this regex: [`(?<!@)@(?!@)|[^ABC@]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%40)%40(%3f!%40)%7c%5b%5eABC%40%5d&i=AXBY%40%40CZ&r=%3f) but it is much simpler to use the hint of Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: What is the expecred output for `AXYB` when `A`, `XY`, `YB` are known? Should it be `AXY?` or `A?YB`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample to the hint of Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
var str = "AXBY@@CZ@A";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "@@|[ABC]").Cast<Match>();
var replaced = string.Join("?", matches.Select(x => x.Value));
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ZoVgMk)

Returns `A?B?@@?C?A` for input `AXBY@@CZ@A`.

Keep in mind the hint of Dmitry Bychenko. This sample doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Yeah, I would do it like this. This can further be enhanced depending on the requirements.